# expressJS exporting other things in addition to app

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, export

In my web application (I'm using expressJS), there are many services (such as mongoDB connection, MQTT connection, etc.) that need to be executed once the whole application is executed (using **npm start** command). Therefore, I can make use of these services in my entire application. For example, I want to use my MQTT connection in different files.

My idea is to export the MQTT connection, MongoDB connection, etc. in addition to the **app** this way:

```
//app.js

module.exports = {
   app: app,
   mqttConnection: myMQTTConnection,
   db: myMongoDB
};
```

However, we know that this approach doesn't work (I tested it and got an error saying: *TypeError: app.set is not a function*).

How can I export other things in addition to **app** from **app.js** file?

If my approach is not possible, what other approaches can I use? (considering the fact that many services (such as connecting to a server, etc.) are asynchronous)

Comment: How are you importing and using the `app`?

Comment: I'm not importing the **app** in my entire application. I created my web application using **express-generator** (because I'm an amateur to expressJS). And I use **npm start** to run my application

Comment: *I tested it and got an error saying: TypeError: app.set is not a function* - how did you test it? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Generally you shouldn't export all app dependencies from app.js, this may result in circular dependencies. Create separate modules for that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030744/should-i-use-a-global-variable-to-share-socket-io-instance-across-entire-server/53031041#53031041

Comment: I tested your approach and got [this error] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053147/share-mqtt-client-object-between-files).